# PHP Auto-authorization via link

Tags: php, html, authentication, authorization

I try to do automatic log in form. Here is my HMTL form

```
<input name="login:username" type="text" class="INPUT_USER">
<input name="login:password" type="password" class="INPUT_PASS">
<input type="image" src="login.gif" class="BUTTON" value="" border="0">
```

And this is my username Admin and password Test.

I want when I open this link www.example.com/admin and somehow I submit username and password to be entered automatically in system. Its that possible?

I think something like this http://Admin:Test@example.com/admin

I'll be glad if someone suggested option. Thanks in advance and I apologize if I was not clear.

Comment: If you have auto-authorization, ... why don't you remove authorization check? Is useless.

Comment: @sensorario I know, but should have. Can you help me?

Comment: I cant give you bad suggestion, sorry ^_^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never ever pass passwords by your url's. 
Server have to know that user who enter this url is owner of account it has to log him in.

Solution 1: cookies
Store cookie with token or hashed password so server can check it.

Solution 2: forever logged in - simply - sessions

Comment: Storing the password in a cookie makes it a much easier target for an attacker. Storing the password hash in a cookie is useless, unless the server also accepts the hash itself, in which case the hash *is* the password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to log users in without a password *all the time*. This must be a special case in your scenario.

The correct thing to do would be to generate tokens for your users when they actually need a logon link. You could generate a cryptographically random, secure token and associate that with your user. The token should also have a timestamp to time-limit its use. Then you could even create links with the token included if you want. When the user uses the link (the token), you could invalidate it, resulting in a one time token, or if you need it for a while, invalidate it when they no longer need it (or even periodically, say a token could be valid for a week or a month, after which they would have to renew it by logging in again).

To increase the security of this, you could set up easy multi-factor authentication with TOTP or HOTP and mobile apps like Google Authenticator. That way, even if an attacker has the token, they would still need the users mobile device to be able to log on.

Another control would be to display the last logon time and IP address (approximate location of the client as derived from the client IP) to let your users know if the token was compromised.

You should also have token invalidation in place, ie. your users should be able to remove a token when they think it's compromised.

These are some controls that would actually make it at least somewhat secure.

Storing the password in a cookie is very insecure, storing a password hash in a cookie is pointless. Long (forever) sessions are insecure, the attacker only needs to get hold of the session id once and in the worst case, the user would have no way to invalidate it.